# What is more performance expensive: bind events to all elements inside the box or bind to the whole box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scalability, jquery-events

I have a feed with updates on the website – just like Facebook or Google+ does. Moreover, when page is scrolled down, more and more updates are loading at the bottom (+20 when scrollbars reach the bottom of the page).
Each update is a separated box that have many links inside. I need to bind 'click' events to all these links inside each box and new comings as well.

**What is cheaper from performance point of view?**

1. To bind events to all the links inside every single box:

   ```
   $(box).find('.link1').on('click', …);
   $(box).find('.link2').on('click', …);
   …
   ```
2. Bind an event to the box itself (or even to the feed wrapper) and truck target elements clicked executing necessary function based on clicked target:

   ```
   $(box).on('click', function(e) {
     var target = $(e.target);

     if (target.is('.link1')) …
     if (target.is('.link2')) …
   });
   ```

**How does Facebook/Google+ do  it?** Bind an event to a single link or bind an event to the whole box and then delegate depending on the target?

*Currently, I feel like browser needs a lot of memory to have all necessary DOM objects has events bound, especially when I scroll so much down that there are 200+ updates.*

Comment: Pretty certain binding to all elements is more expensive as binding to the box you can trap the events bubbling up and work on them as you indicate in your second code block.  The bubbling they would do in anycase.

Comment: It really depends on what point of view you're talking about performance - the binding of the events, or the execution of events. When you have dynamic elements that need events bound, use event delegation to the closest static parent. If you don't have dynamic elements, just stick with normal event binding. And if you understand how jQuery works internally with event handling, it's not that memory expensive for all DOM elements to have bound events - they just reference single functions

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime case for event delegation:

```
$('someContainer').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    //'this' is the event target
});
```

See the [documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), specifically the part about "Direct and delegated events".

Comment: I agree. The trade off is speed vs memory. By binding directly on the element (which uses more memory) you can get a faster response. By binding to a parent element you need to wait for the event to bubble up. The difference can be noticible if it travels trough a lot of elements (binding to document is all situations isn't free), also by binding to a parent Elena you can end up in situations where a child element can prevent event bubbling (if you have a lot of event handling code this can get tricky)